# How can I set the margin of a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JLabel` that I want to add a margin to. It looks like this:

[image]

I read about setting an empty border with a certain thickness, but this would replace the current border. How can I add this margin?

Comment: Excuse the strange placeholder text...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> "I read about setting an empty border with a certain thickness, but this would replace the current border. How can I add this margin?"

See [CompoundBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/CompoundBorder.html)

> A composite Border class used to compose two Border objects into a single border by nesting an inside Border object within the insets of an outside Border object. For example, this class may be used to add blank margin space to a component with an existing decorative border:

```
Border border = comp.getBorder();
Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10);
comp.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(border, margin));
```

Also see [EmptyBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html#EmptyBorder%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: You should only do this once though if you do this inside a CellRenderer.  Otherwise, it will continue to add addition borders each time